# To check if App actually uses permissions mentioned in Manifest file

Tags: android

How can one check if an app is actually using the permissions it asked for in its manifest file. 
Note: Source code of app will be provided.
According to me, we can manually solve this problem. But can't generalize it.
Any guidance to solve it will be appreciated.

Comment: Ultimately, you cannot, unless you can prove that the code is entirely static.  However, you can determine with a carefully instrumented platform if it has done so in a particular execution session.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use [apkinspector](https://github.com/honeynet/apkinspector/). This will show you exactly in the code where permissions are used.
2. You could rebuild the apk and see when it crashes, using logcat to see what permission what requested.

[image]

Comment: Not true.  Analysis of this form fails to account for reflection, native code or self modifying code, and unreached code - so it has both false negatives and false positives.  Also, logcat will not necessarily indicate what permission is missing, even as it may (or may not) give a hint as to what task failed.

Comment: As noted by the OP, the source code is provided. This will facilitate results. Obviously the OP will QA results via verification.

Comment: The source code may (if simple or painstakingly examined) be enough to determine if the question is *answerable* - but the result of that analysis may also be that the runtime behavior of the program cannot be known, without executing it - and then only known for that particular execution.